# RAM not working with my motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I bought new RAM modules: [Kingston 8GB(2x4GB) KIT DDR3 1333MHz CL9 HyperX Fury](http://www.kingston.com/en/hyperx/memory/fury) and the motherboard is an [ASUS M4A785TD-M EVO](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A785TDM_EVO/specifications/). Does anyone know what could be the problem? After turning on the computer with the memory doesn’t do anything, just spinning fans.

Frequency is fine, it may be timing? I'm not familiar with it.

edit:
I found nothing in the manual. There is a list of tested memory, but does not include 4 gigabytes modules. CPU = AMD Athlon II X4, power source = 350W, graphic card = internal, HDD = WD 500GB, . I can't get into bios, I can't get any output from a graphic card, no beeps. When I put the old memory (2x 2GB 1333Mhz), everything runs fine and boots up an operating system (CentOS). A combination of old and new memory doesn't work too.

Comment: Did you check the motherboard's user manual? There might be some pecularity that you simply failed to consider...wow this brings memories of fitting new memory in 386 systems.

Comment: What cpu do you have?

Comment: I just edited the question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Timing or chip configuration is not included in the manual. But I tried to install new bios and now it is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update BIOS to newer version helped. Version 2104 from 2010/09/30 works for me.

1. Download new bios version from [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A785TDM_EVO/HelpDesk_Download/)
2. Extract and copy it to USB Flash disk.
3. Restart PC, connect flash disk, and press  to open BIOS configuration
4. Find ASUS EZ2 Flash utility, press
5. By  switch to the flash disk drive and press
6. Process automatically reboots the system when done